# How to sort hashmap String, Collection<String []>> by String[index]

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, sorting

i want sort this Map:

```
Map<String, Collection<String[]>> map = new HashMap<String, Collection<String[]>>();
```

In map is for example:

```
String key = "MyKey";
Collection<String[]> values = new ArrayList<String[]>();
map.put(key, values);

String[] firstValues = { "John", "21", "M"};
values.add(firstValues); //Name, Age, Gender

String[] secondValues = { "Jane", "31", "W"};
values.add(secondValues);
```

etc.

so finnaly, i have:
map with:

```
Mykey : [["John", "21", "M"], ["Eve", "31", "W"]];
```

And i want do:

```
Collection<String[]> values = map.get(key);
```

and then sort by specific index, for example by first index(name) alphabetically, or
by second index(age). So after first sort will be:

```
Mykey : [["Eve", "31", "W"], ["John", "21", "M"]];
```

after second sort:

```
Mykey : [["John", "21", "M"], ["Eve", "31", "W"]];
```

Comment: A `Collection` is not necessarily ordered. You might want to use `List` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the API `java.util.Collections.sort(List list, Comparator c)` which specifies a comparator, and implement it as you wish (one for name, and another one for age)

Also, instead of using `String[]{name, age, gender}` as elements, create a class `Person` having these variables as members. I would probably place the two comparators you want inside this class as well:

```
public static final Comparator<Person> AGE_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        // implement
    }
};
```

Now you could simply call

```
Collections.sort(map.get(key), Person.AGE_COMPARATOR);
```

Assuming you used the List interface instead of the Collection interface as @Vatev suggested:

```
Map<String, List<Person>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Person>>();
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code looks to me like something a developer experienced in dynamic languages such as Ruby would write. You'll probably find out that this is not your best avenue with Java. You should model your `String[]` with an appropriate object containing those strings as properties.

Also I think that the map part of your question is not very relevant—you are in effect dealing with a collection of objects that you need to sort by one of the properties. That you happen to have several such collections in a map doesn't influence the solution.

The sorting itself is done as @Havard Geithus has already advised you.